# Rails version error (inconsistency)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

When I try to run `rails s` or `rails c` I get the following error:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2
```

so I try `ruby -v` and get:

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
```

and when I do `which ruby` I get:

```
/home/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
```

Even if I explicitly run `rvm use 2.1.2` I still get the same error.

Can somebody please explain me what is wrong??

Comment: Did you try running `bundle install` after `rvm use 2.1.2`?

Comment: why not just specify `2.3.1` in the `Gemfile` and then set that as the default version? Changes are unlikely to be dramatic. Upgrading ruby for an app is usually pretty easy.

Comment: @sahil, I did, I get the same error: `Your Ruby version is 2.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1`

Comment: @toddmetheny, I did. I get then another error while running `bundle install` which apparently has to do which `raindrops` gem - `Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.` :-(

Comment: does it work when you comment out raindrops and `bundle`? Is raindrops still maintained? Looks old.

Comment: Is the ruby gem version issue still there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - problem was old version of raindrops Gem.

Since I never use `bundle update`, I had an old version of it. The `Gemfile.lock` looked like this:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
      :
      :
    raindrops (0.12.0)
      :
      :
    unicorn (4.7.0)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
```

I deleted the line of the independent gem (0.12.0) and ran `bundle install`. I got this gem back with version 0.17.0.